# WPF - Odd Behavior Binding Issue with One Color

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window that contains a navigation-related user control that has a layout that is largely driven by data binding. The data context is a "Status" object that has a "StatusStyle" sub-object which contains all the of the formatting, like foreground, background, font size, etc...

When this control's data context's status is set to an "incomplete" status, it gets a new StatusStyle object that defines a white background (default is green), and a very dark gray foreground (#333333).

Everything tested out perfectly and we had several testers that had no problems whatsoever. Then we rolled this code out to a small group of people in production and suddenly those people are randomly seeing this control get a white background and a **white foreground**.

[image: Screenshot]

I -know- the binding is working because the control wouldn't get a white background if it didn't. All of the other style parameters are also working (font size, etc).

What's even more bizarre is that the ONLY thing affected seems to be this one dark gray color. Every other place in the application that uses that same color (TextBlocks, etc) all end up with white text when this problem occurs.

The entire color scheme is all defined in the same place in the exact same way:

```
namespace Styling.Colors
{
  public static class Fonts
  {
    public static Color DarkBlue { get; set; } = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#003366");
    public static Color DarkGray { get; set; } = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#333333");
    ...etc...
  }

  public static class FontBrushes
  {
    public static SolidColorBrush DarkBlue { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Fonts.DarkBlue);
    public static SolidColorBrush DarkGray { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Fonts.DarkGray);
    ...etc...
  }
}
```

Here's an example of it being used in XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static colors:FontBrushes.DarkGray}}" />
</Style>
```

...and also a usage in code-behind:

```
public override SolidColorBrush ForegroundColor { get; set; } = Styling.Colors.FontBrushes.DarkGray;
```

Again, in all places that reference this one particular color, it randomly comes out white for some users in production, and I cannot reproduce it (and it never showed up in pre-production testing). When I test, it always looks correct. All other colors within that same color scheme look correct.

All I can think of at this point is that it's some kind of resource problem, like a memory or graphics problem, but I'm just scratching my head here. It's a static brush, so I would assume it would only ever get allocated once, and it would continue to be referenced. There's no code that sets nor modifies the color - it only ever just reads the brush.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay, I have a small breakthrough here. It appears that there is a separate, 3rd party plugin that is also running within the same application and when it launches, it has some kind of theme manager that adds a new resource dictionary into the merged dictionaries:

System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary) new StyleResources());

...and there are some rules in there that are almost certainly responsible for changing the color of the brush. However, I do not have access to the code for this theme manager / style dictionary, so is there a good way to just programmatically dump the entirety of the resource dictionaries so that it can be saved by one of the users and then sent to me for inspection?

Comment: There's not much to go on here, without a [mcve]. Are you using the out-of-the-box `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: I realize there's not much to go on. I was hoping someone could maybe confirm whether a resource issue could cause the type of behavior being described. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "out-of-the-box" here?

Comment: If you have to ask, you are probably using Microsoft's `ResourceDictionary`. It's a good way of leaking memory, resources (and performance). We used https://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

Comment: _is there a good way to just programmatically dump the entirety of the resource dictionaries so that it can be saved by one of the users and then sent to me for inspection?_ `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` in combination with `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter` should get you going